# setting up dual google analytics on 1 website

Tags: google-analytics

Long story short, i have two website url's

www.somewebsiteA.com
www.somewebsiteB.com

Both domains point to the same server.

I created a google analytics account, and setup the two urls and have individual analytics keys for them.

Is this how i should paste the google code into the pages?

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'somewebsiteA.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  ga('create', 'UA-12345678-2', 'somewebsiteB.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I'm not entirely certain. It seems like somewebsiteB.com isnt working.

Thanks!

Comment: On the tracking admin panel side, if i go to website data for somewebsiteA, i can see people on somewebsiteB but the reverse does not seem to work.

Comment: I found this but their code is different. Does that matter? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en&ref_topic=2772342

Comment: no, that's cross-domain tracking, which is for if you want both sites to use the same account and the visitor tracking to carry over from one domain to the other, which is the opposite of what you are looking for.. or is it? Do you want the traffic from both domains to be in the same reports, or do you want them to be treated separate?

Comment: Preferably i would like to have both domains to be viewed on the same report.

Comment: hmm okay, well if you want both domains to be viewed on the same report, then you don't need 2 separate account numbers. Just use one on both domains. This will make traffic flow to a single place. However, you *will* need to implement the cross-domain tracking. Here is a link to the UA version https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain

Comment: Using what you did below, it seems to be working.

Comment: Could always use [Google Tag Manager](http://www.google.com/tagmanager/) to deploy multiple tags. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give each one their own namespace:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');


  ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', {'cookieDomain':'somewebsiteA.com', 'name':'siteA'});
  ga('siteA.send', 'pageview'); 

  ga('create', 'UA-12345678-2', {'cookieDomain':'somewebsiteB.com','name':'siteB'});
  ga('siteB.send', 'pageview');


</script>
```

Comment: This seems like what i need! Thanks!